# Do guidelines in ConstraintLayout support RTL

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Do Guidelines in `ConstraintLayout` support RTL? 
I'm creating a `View` that has a profile picture and user info to its right. I want the picture to take 30% of the width while the username and details take 70%. Is this a valid use case for Guidelines? I am aware of other implementations but I was wondering whether or not guidelines can be used here.
The problem I'm facing is that the guideline remains in it's position on the left after changing the devices language to a RTL language

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWsqB.png)

**Here is the xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:text="Full Name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:text="Android Developer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.30" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

** UPDATE ** The [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38101983) on this issue is now marked as fixed by Google.
** END UPDATE **

It seems like the Android team missed this issue.

Percent is calculated from the left only.

So to support RTL you can declare a constant in values/dimens.xml, for example:

```
<resources>
     <item name="my_percent" format="float" type="dimen">0.3</item>
</resources>
```

And override this value with its `100-mypercent` in `values-ldrtl/dimens.xml` file.

```
<resources>
     <item name="my_percent" format="float" type="dimen">0.7</item>
</resources>
```

Use it:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@dimen/my_percent" />
```

- If you prefer to re-write a complete layout version for RTL, you can skip declaring dimensions, and use `layout-ldrtl/` directory for the RTL version.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked the issue tracker and found it has been reported: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38101983

Comment: The issue is officially resolved in ConstraintLayout 1.1.0 beta 3
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/10/constraintlayout-110-beta-3-is-now.html

Comment: I tested the 1.1.0 beta 3. The vertical guideline seems to compute from the right side when using RTL. However the horizontal guideline now computes from the bottom which I think is wrong.  20% from the top still 20% in RTL, not 80%.